# Get last 5 days with posts

Tags: loop, date

I am trying to get a solution to this question of mine
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487639/date-base-archive-on-wordpress-homepage

I am trying with multiple loops, if thats possible. But I need to know whether a day has posts or not.

Is there any way I can get last 5 days that has posts and create loops for them? Something like this

```
<?php
$last5days = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT DATE(MAX(post_date)) FROM {$wpdb->posts} LIMIT 5");

$day1 = $last5days[0];
$day2 = $last5days[1];
$day3 = $last5days[2];
$day4 = $last5days[3];
$day5 = $last5days[4];

// The Query
$query1 = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'products', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'day'=> $day1) );

// The Loop
while ( $query1->have_posts() ) {
    $query1->the_post(); ?>
    <!-- My Loop Codes Goes Here -->
<?php
}
wp_reset_postdata();

/*
 * The Rest Loops Goes Here
*/

$query5 = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'products', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'day'=> $day1) );

// The Final (5th) Loop
while( $query5->have_posts() ) {
    $query5->the_post();?>
    <!-- My Loop Codes Goes Here -->
<?php
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: You should not duplicate questions across the network. Moderators can migrate questions if need be. And you should search the site before posting. I see several questions about date based post lists over on the right under "Related". See if any of those help.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Thanks for the heads up, I'll keep that in mind. Although I see no reason to mark this question as the duplicate of my other question I mentioned in this question. I thought of a solution and asked help for that here. I already visited the related questions (displayed while I was constructing this question) and none of them were helpful except one (it's one of YOUR replies and in fact, my edit reflects that I tried the codes found in that Q&A). I really don't have any intention to flood the community with dups, but at least, I tried. I hope you understand.